# Lower central series in a free pro-p group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, profinite-groups, p-groups, nilpotent-groups

Let $F$ be a nonabelian finitely generated free pro-$p$ group, $H \leq_c F$ of infinite index. Denote by $\{F_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ the lower central series of $F$, and set $r_n = [F : F_nH]$.

Is it poosible that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $r_n < \infty$ ?

If this is possible, I would like to have a bound from below on the growth rate $r_n \rightarrow \infty$.